# Can I export attachments using Command Line Dataloader and use ANT to get it to FTP site/Google drive

Tags: data-loader, after-trigger, ftp, google-drive, ant-script

**Background:**

I want to run an after update opportunity trigger that would fetch all the opportunity records as well as attachments and then transfer it to a third party-website. In order to do that, I am first trying to fetch the salesforce data and attachments with some free tool/code and upload it to FTP site/Google drive. From FTP/google drive I would pick the data and get to the third party site.

**My question:**
Can I extract attachments using Command Line Dataloader and use ANT to send it to FTP site or Google drive. What format would the attachments be extracted using Dataloader? I don't want to use any paid tool e.g. Jitterbit e.t.c, since I don't have the budget for that. So I am wondering if Command Line Dataloader would be good enough to extract attachments?

Thanks

Comment: What does the trigger have to do with this process?

Comment: So whenever a user associates an attachment to the Opportunity, I have to initiate a process that would copy that opportunity data as well as attachments to the third-party site. So I thought I would have to run an after update trigger on opportunity to make sure there has been an addition/update to opportunity record that needs to be transferred over to third-party site.

Comment: Where (i.e. on which machine) would ANT/command line dataloader run? When? Are you bound to ANT/ command line dataloader for this task?

Comment: oh if I would need a specific local machine to export the data and get the data transferred from there to FTP , it might not be the best solution for me.